# referencing a cell in a cell id

Tags: excel, cell

I have an excel sheet where cell B30 returns a value of 26 using the Match function. This means that in cell M26 there is a value I want to retrieve.
How do I retrieve the value of M26 without writing =M26 as the value 26 will change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
=INDEX(M:M,B30)
```

This will work as long as you know the cell you want will be in column M.

Comment: I'm not sure you need CELL function - =INDEX(M:M,B30) should suffice